# "TypeError: undefined is not a constructor" with Capybara (PhantomJS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, capybara

I have a JavaScript error with Capybara feature test.
But the error is not occurring with normal chrome browser.
The JavaScript code is below.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var enable = function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(e){ e.disabled = false });
  }
  /* do something ..*/
  enable();
}
```

The error message is `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'form.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(e){ e.disabled = false })')`.
I think it is related to `forEach` returns undefined.

Comment: no, `forEach` does and should return undefined - not all implementations of `NodeList` (what querySelectorAll returns) have a `forEach` method though - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I thought PhantomJS is almost same as Chrome. But I've got it's not correct.Thank you!

Comment: something like `[].forEach.call(form.querySelectorAll('input'), function(e){ e.disabled = false });`

Comment: Thanks. I will try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` is an ES 5.1/6 method, but the current version of PhantomJS only supports up to ES 5.  You will need to either polyfill forEach or rewrite your code using ES 5 compatible methods.

Comment: I got it! I will try it another way or use polyfill. Thanks!